# Show different report in Oracle based on parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, report

I'm using Oracle report builder and I have to show summary and detail reports. This tool does not have drilldown capability. I need it to show the either the detail or the summary report based on a parameter that the user enters at the beginning. Can anyone tell me how to dynamically display either one or the other report based on the user parameter entered?

Answer (score 0):

You will use a repeating frame to display the content and you can set the visibility of this frame according to the value of your report parameter.

So you will just have two of these - one for your first select and another one for the second.